# Rails 4 - CanCanCan - expression

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, cancancan

I am trying to define abilities in my ability.rb using CanCanCan.

I'm not sure whether this is a valid expression - I can't find examples in the wiki that deal with this.

I have a model called Vision. Vision has a boolean attribute called :public and another attribute called :public_vision

If :public is true, then I want to create an ability to read the :public vision

I have tried this:

```
   can :read, Vision.public_vision, :public => true
```

Is this valid syntax? I can't test my abilities file yet because there are too many bits of ruby that I can't comment out.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed this, to:

can :read, Vision, [:public_vision]

Then, in the view, you only show a link if :public is true.

I found the Resource Attributes section on the CanCanCan wiki. So far so good.